# java stream sort/filter through list by properties

Tags: java, sorting, collections, lambda

I have some logic that will create notifications based on users that are inactive. I am getting a list of users that have the following properties. What I am trying to do is only trigger my create notification method if a department has an inactive user. So given the below list, basically 1 notification would get created saying there is an inactive user in dept 1 and another notification for dept 2. Hope this makes sense

```
users:
{name: John, active: f, deptId: 1}
{name: Jane, active: f, deptId: 1}
{name: Mike, active: t, deptId: 1}
{name: Joe, active: f, deptId: 2}
{name: Jim, active: t, deptId: 2}
```

My current code basically would get this list, and then check the active flag on each one and create a notification for each user - but I need to refactor that.

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
for(User u : users){
    if(u != null && u.getActive == false){
        ....create Notification method
```

What would be the best way to group these by department and then only checking if there is an active flag of false for each of those groups and creating 1 notification rather than a notification for each user that is inactive?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find the following snippet helpful:

```
public Map<String, List<User>> getInactiveUsersByDepartment(List<User> allUsers) {
    return allUsers.stream().filter(user -> user != null).filter(user -> !user.getActive()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getDepartment));
}
```

Comment: Actually I made a typo and left something out. The list is not actually coming from the User domain - It is in another table called UserUnprocessed which has a userId foreign key to the User table, so to check those properties it would need to be

Comment: UserUnprocessed.getUser().getDepartment - would I still be able to use the method you wrote out?

Answer (score 0):

Start with filtering out `null` and active users as you're only intersted in those who're inactive. Afterwards, group the result by the department ID. Use the resulting map to iterate over the key set, i.e. the departments with inactive users:

```
users.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(((Predicate<User>) User::isActive).negate())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getDeptId))
        .keySet().forEach(Notifier::notifyDepartment);
```

Note that you could also use lambda expressions instead of method references (e.g. `user -> !user.isActive()`), it's just a matter of style.

You can use this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to play around with the implementation, it simply prints out the affected departments:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReportInactiveUsers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User u1 = new User("John", false, 1);
        User u2 = new User("Jane", false, 1);
        User u3 = new User("Mike", true, 1);
        User u4 = new User("Joe", false, 2);
        User u5 = new User("Jim", true, 2);
        User u6 = null;
        List<User> users = Arrays.asList(u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6);

        users.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(((Predicate<User>) User::isActive).negate())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getDeptId))
                .keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static class User {
        private String name;
        private boolean active;
        private int deptId;

        public User(String name, boolean active, int deptId) {
            this.name = name;
            this.active = active;
            this.deptId = deptId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public int getDeptId() {
            return deptId;
        }
    }

}
```